# How to change number of iterations in maxent classifier for POS Tagging in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, classification, nltk

I am trying to perform POS tagging using `ClassifierBasedPOSTagger` with `classifier_builder=MaxentClassifier.train`. Here is the piece of code:

```
from nltk.tag.sequential import ClassifierBasedPOSTagger
from nltk.classify import MaxentClassifier
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')
size = int(len(brown_tagged_sents) * 0.9)

train_sents = brown_tagged_sents[:size]
test_sents = brown_tagged_sents[size:]

me_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_sents, classifier_builder=MaxentClassifier.train)
print(me_tagger.evaluate(test_sents))
```

But after an hour of running the code, I see that it is still initialising the `ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_sents, classifier_builder=MaxentClassifier.train)`. In the output, I can see the following piece of code running:

```
  ==> Training (100 iterations)

  Iteration    Log Likelihood    Accuracy
  ---------------------------------------
         1          -5.35659        0.007
         2          -0.85922        0.953
         3          -0.56125        0.986
```

I think the iterations are going to be 100 before the classifier is ready to tag parts of speech to any input. That would take whole day I suppose. Why is it taking so much time? And will decreasing the iterations make this code a bit practical(meaning reduce the time and still be useful enough), and if yes, then how to decrease those iterations?

**EDIT**

After 1.5 hours, I get the following output:

```
  ==> Training (100 iterations)

  Iteration    Log Likelihood    Accuracy
  ---------------------------------------
         1          -5.35659        0.007
         2          -0.85922        0.953
         3          -0.56125        0.986
E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\maxent.py:1310: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
  exp_nf_delta = 2 ** nf_delta
E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\maxent.py:1312: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  sum1 = numpy.sum(exp_nf_delta * A, axis=0)
E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\maxent.py:1313: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  sum2 = numpy.sum(nf_exp_nf_delta * A, axis=0)
         Final               nan        0.991
0.892155885577594
```

Was the algorithm supposed to get to `100 iterations` as specified in the first line of the output and because of the error it didn't? And is there any possible way of reducing the time it took for training?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set parameter value of `max_iter` to desired number.

**Code:**

```
from nltk.tag.sequential import ClassifierBasedPOSTagger
from nltk.classify import MaxentClassifier
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')
# Change size based on your requirement
size = int(len(brown_tagged_sents) * 0.05)
print("size:",size)

train_sents = brown_tagged_sents[:size]
test_sents = brown_tagged_sents[size:]

#me_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_sents, classifier_builder=MaxentClassifier.train)
me_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_sents, classifier_builder=lambda train_feats: MaxentClassifier.train(train_feats, max_iter=15))
print(me_tagger.evaluate(test_sents))
```

**Output:**

```
('size:', 231)
  ==> Training (15 iterations)

  Iteration    Log Likelihood    Accuracy
  ---------------------------------------
         1          -4.67283        0.013
         2          -0.89282        0.964
         3          -0.56137        0.998
         4          -0.40573        0.999
         5          -0.31761        0.999
         6          -0.26107        0.999
         7          -0.22175        0.999
         8          -0.19284        0.999
         9          -0.17067        0.999
        10          -0.15315        0.999
        11          -0.13894        0.999
        12          -0.12719        0.999
        13          -0.11730        0.999
        14          -0.10887        0.999
     Final          -0.10159        0.999
0.787489765499
```

**For Edit**:

Those messages are RuntimeWarnings and not errors.

As after 4th iteration it found `Log Likelihood = nan`, so it stopped processing further. So, it became final iteration.

Comment: Can you tell me how much time does this piece of code takes to execute on your computer?

Comment: Because of `size = int(len(brown_tagged_sents) * 0.05)` it took around 4-5 minutes in my system.

Comment: It takes around 1 hour in my system. What can be the possible issue? I installed scipy later on when I came to know that scipy and numpy will make it run faster. Do I need to restart after installing scipy?

Comment: As I also mentioned in my previous comment also that change in execution time is because of change in size of training data. I changed `size = int(len(brown_tagged_sents) * 0.9)` to `size = int(len(brown_tagged_sents) * 0.05)`. From 90% to 5% of complete corpus.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't pay attention to that. Thank you so much.